# Differences between chars created by read() and harcodded (C Language)

Tags: c

I try to make a login function, but I got stuck ...

I have two apps ( server and client). I send from client to server an username created by `read(0,username,100)`.

In server, if I want to check that username introduced in client by read (for example: `test`) is equal to `"test"` with `strcmp(username,"test") == 0`, it is not equal and I don't know why.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the protocol, but it may be due to newline character or other control character. Did you check the content of `username` by printing it?

Comment: It might be that, there is no `'\0'` so you could `ssize_t length = read(0, username, sizeof(username) - 1); if (length == -1) handleErrorAndExitProbably(); username[length] = '\0';` Your code is incomplete and thus, it's hard or impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible reasons, but luckily not SO MANY,

1. You could be passing the user name without passing the `'\0'` `nul` terminator, in that case (and probably in any case just to be sure), you could do this

   ```
   char username[100];
   ssize_t length;
   if ((length = read(0, username, sizeof(username) - 1)) == -1) 
       pleaseAbortSubsequentOperationsOn_username();
   username[length] = '\0';
   ```

   would ensure that, `username` is `nul` terminated. Of course, there might be embeded `'\0'`'s in the data sent from the other end and many other subtleties, but this could help if it's just plain text that you are sending from the other end.

   Also note another limitation is for a string of more than `99` characters, which would be silently truncated with this approach.

   I mean that this is insufficient, but it might help you go in the right direction.
2. It could be possible that there is a `'\n'` or some other control characater ([see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960312/differences-between-chars-created-by-read-and-harcodded-c-language#comment55678069_33960312)) and it's being compared by `strcmp()` leading to a false comparison. So you could check that too, or write a comparison function that ignores white spaces, or remove leading/trailing white spaces from the read string.

As you can figure out these problems might come in different combinations so checking for that with a `printf()` would help you know which problem it is.

As for the `'\0'` terminator problem, you would need a memory debugger like [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org), or the equivalent for your environment. But the simple fix suggested in the first point above would be sufficient for testing.